# Editing added field in raster attribute table using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, raster-attribute-table

I have a raster file in tiff format and this raster file has an attribute table already. What I want to do is to populate each original values with a new value and display the map with new underlying value.

Options:

1. I added a new field (CBD_kg_m3) to this attribute table, but I can not edit it. Is there a way that I edit it and select this column to display in map?
2. Maybe I can change the value of the original layer, but I still need to be able to edit the attribute table.

[image]

Comment: Please always decide whether you wish to ask about ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro in a particular question. The picture looks like ArcMap so I’ll remove reference to ArcGIS Pro. You can always ask about that in a separate question.

Comment: Use field calculator and lookup when done editing.